# Magento2 403 Forbidden var folder

Tags: magento2, error, http-status-403

> 403 Forbidden

Why do not I have a browser access to `magento-domain/var/import/*` files?

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional by design. Files stored in the `var` folder should not be publicly visible to the world to access as it also contains various Magento logs/reports/files that aren't meant for users to see in the browser.

It seems like you would want to access a file like that via SFTP. If you absolutely must have it accessible from the browser, you might consider moving it somewhere in the `pub/media` folder, which is publicly accessible from the browser.

I would recommend considering any security implications of moving any files from `var` to `pub/media`.

**Reason For 403 Forbidden**

This is why you get the 403 forbidden on the `var` folder. If the site is running from apache, the `var/.htaccess` file is preventing access on purpose

If the site is running from nginx, I'm betting there is a rule in the nginx config to block requests to the `var` folder:

In `var/.htaccess`:

```
<IfVersion < 2.4>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
    Require all denied
</IfVersion>
```